# Display data from database using Javascript in Java code

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I am using java and jsp to display my data.
I want to use javascript to display data from database on select of item from dropdown list.
i.e. i have a form where on selecting an item from a dropdown list the information of that item should be displayed.

How should I start it?

Comment: You want the data to show up without a reload of the page?

Comment: @Till Helge Helwig:
yes.. on select of that item data should be displayed for user to view... later i will do other processing..

Comment: Well...you need to trigger an AJAX call when an item is selected. Then you need a webservice from which you can retrieve the data that belongs to the entry. I would suggest using JSON as transfer format, because it's easiest to handle. There should be loads of information around about how to do AJAX calls from JSP pages. (It's not even related to JSP...you can do it with plain HTML and JavaScript.)

Comment: @Till Helge Helwig: 
Thanks for the guidance..

Comment: @SeeyaK: Check answer in this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097754/html-page-calls-jsp-file. Pass id of the select there