# HTML page calls JSP file

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

I have a HTML page on my computer and a JSP file on a distant server.

Now how do I,

**Display content from the JSP file into the HTML page.**

The HTML page must be strictly HTML (no server-side language), but can use AJAX/JavaScript.

Is it even possible to get the information from the server through the JSP page without turning the HTML page into a JSP file itself?  How would I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
// I have jquery.js under js directory in my webapp
<script type="text/javascript">
  var url = "my.jsp";
  $(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url : url, // Pass you Servlet/ JSP Url
            dataType : 'html',
            success : function(response) {
                alert('Success');
                $('#output').html(response);
            },
            error : function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(request.status + ', Error: ' + request.statusText);
                           // perform tasks for error 
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%

out.println("<h1>Hello World</h1>"); // Write html values here
%>
```

Your HTML

....
`<div id="output"></div>`

Comment: Thanks, Hardik.  I believe this is exactly what I'm looking for.  Now, is running a JSP session possible in the same HTML page?  Essentially, the initial JSP contact would be to log in the user.

Comment: Hardik: it won't let me vote because my rep point is too low right now... Sorry

Answer (score 0):

with using Ajax:

```
function ClickMe_Click()
{
    $.ajax({
        type:       "post",
        url:        "path/your.jsp",
        data:       {"param":"val"},
        success:    function(msg) {
                            alert(msg.data);//your info from jsp
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError);
            }  
    });

}
```